# Powershell script Unable to create folder after page file settings

Tags: powershell

The powershell script which I have does the page file settings and then creates folders in the Temporary Storage(Z: drive). I have scheduled the script in task scheduler But the execution is intermittent for folder creation.

The Page file settings are done but the folder creation works for some time and some time it doesn't.

The script is:

```
$computer = Get-Wmiobject Win32_computersystem -EnableAllPrivileges
$computer.AutomaticManagedPageFile = $false
$computer.Put()
$CurrentPageFile = Get-WmiObject -Query "select * from Win32_PageFileSetting where name= 'C:\\pagefile.sys'"
$CurrentPageFile.delete()
Set-WMIInstance -Class Win32_PageFileSetting -Arguments @{name="Z:\pagefile.sys";Initialsize=0;MaximumSize=0}
Set-WMIInstance -Class Win32_PageFileSetting -Arguments @{name="D:\pagefile.sys";Initialsize=0;MaximumSize=0}
$a = new-object -ComObject scripting.filesystemobject
$a.CreateFolder("Z:\MSSQL")
$a.CreateFolder("Z:\MSSQL\DATA")
```

Note: This script works fine on all remote servers except DB servers if that has any relation.

Please have a look and help me.

Comment: is there any reason to not use `new-item -ItemType directory` ?

Comment: Hey apologies for late reply.. i used that as well but the execution is still intermittent..

Comment: Hey any help will be appreciated